# Window property and Checkbox databinding xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have been a few hours now trying to understand how to do data-binding.
Initially I was following some examples but they all show to do the databinding using {Binding Source={StaticResource myObject}, Path=myObject.myProperty}

or {Binding Path=myObject.myProperty}

Nothing of this seem to bind the Config object inside the controller that is inside the Window.

If I do the binding as an StaticResource it does the binding to an object of the Controller class but is NOT the object that is created inside the window class, this Config seems to be a new separate instance. This is the part I don't understand. If someone could explain or give me some reference where to look I would greatly appreciate it.

This is some code very simplified

Window1.cs

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.UI.Main"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"      
        xmlns:controller="clr-namespace:Sample.Controller"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SampleApp" Height="600" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <controller:PublisherController x:Key="oController" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Window.Resources>    
<CheckBox x:Name="chkBoxShowRoom" Style="{StaticResource checkBoxTemplate}" Content="{StaticResource configShowRoom}"  IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource oController}, Path=Config.ShowRoom}"/>
```

Then my Window1.cs

```
public partial class Main : Window
    {
        public PublisherController Controller { get; set; }
```

Then Controller.cs

```
 public class PublisherController
    {

        public Configuration Config { get; set; }
```

Then the Configuration.cs

```
public class Configuration : AbstractEntity, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
  private bool _ShowRoom;
        public bool ShowRoom
        {
            get
            {
                return _ShowRoom;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != _ShowRoom)
                {
                    this._ShowRoom = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: Are you creating another `PublisherController` in your window constructor? That `oController` resource is an instance all by itself. I suggest you omit the resource, and assign `DataContext = new PublisherController();` in the window constructor after `InitializeComponent()` is called. Then bind like `IsChecked="{Binding Config.ShowRoom}"`. I don't know what you're doing with that `Controller` property of the window, but change it to this: `public PublisherController Controller => DataContext as PublisherController;`

Comment: ...that'll let your code behind interact with the viewmodel without a cast, if there's any need for the code behind to do that. If not, omit the `Controller` property entirely.